# The post request keeps asking for data that were already sent

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm building a register page that will save the data in an API but it keeps returning an `error 400 bad request` and even if I send all the data correctly it says the e-mail and the password are required. I checked and the e-mail and the password is being sent correctly according to what is being typed in the form.

```
const [manager, setManager] = useState({
      company: "" ,
      email: "",
      password: "",
      accessLevel:1
    
  })
  
  console.log(manager)
 const  handleSubmit = () => {
      axios.post(`https://reembolsa-ai-api.herokuapp.com/register`, {manager})
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };
      
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const onFinish = () => {
    handleSubmit();
    form.resetFields();
  };
  
    return (
      
        <Container>
        <Titulo>Cadastro</Titulo>
      <StyledForm
        {...layout}
        form={form}
        name="basic"
        initialValues={{
          remember: true,
        }}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      >
        <StyledLabel>Empresa</StyledLabel>
        <Form.Item
          name="company"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Digite o nome da sua empresa',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <StyledInput onChange={({target: {value}}) =>
        setManager({...manager, company: value})}  placeholder="Insira o nome da sua empresa" value={manager.company}/>
        </Form.Item>
        <StyledLabel>E-mail</StyledLabel>
        <Form.Item
          name="email"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Digite um e-mail válido',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <StyledInput onChange={({target: {value}}) =>
        setManager({...manager, email: value})} placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" value={manager.email} />
        </Form.Item>
  
        <StyledLabel>Senha</StyledLabel>
        <Form.Item
          name="password"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Digite uma senha',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <StyledInputPassword  onChange={({target: {value}}) =>
        setManager({...manager, password: value})} placeholder="Insira sua senha" value={manager.password}/>
        </Form.Item>
        <StyledLabel>Confirme sua senha</StyledLabel>
        <Form.Item
          name="confirmPassword"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Confirme sua senha',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <StyledInputPassword placeholder="Confirme sua Senha"/>
          </Form.Item>
          <ContainerButtons>
            <Form.Item {...tailLayout} >
            <StyledButtonRed to="/login" >
              <BiDownArrow/>
            </StyledButtonRed>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item {...tailLayout} >
            <StyledButtonGreen type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              <BiUpArrow/>
            </StyledButtonGreen>
            </Form.Item>
          </ContainerButtons>
        
      </StyledForm>
      </Container>
    );
  };
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you also include what the response says specifically?

Comment: If  you log `error.response` instead of just `error` to the console when there is an error, you'll notice that the error message says `"Email and password are required"` even though email and password are present. This would  suggest that it's an issue with your backend validation.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a problem on the backend. Check the correctness of the data structure you are transmitting